# PAYMENT.CAPTURE.COMPLETED: How to get parent payment?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-webhooks

When getting an event PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED in a webhook, you can use this code to get more information about the payer:

```
$resource = $webhookEvent->getResource();
$Payment = \Paypal\Api\Payment::get($resource->parent_payment, $apiContext);
$Payer = $Payment->getPayer();
$Payerinfo = $Payer->getPayerInfo();
```

Now I updated to SDK V2, and get PAYMENT.CAPTURE.COMPLETED-events. How does this work here? It seems there is no $resource->parent_payment. I tried something like:

```
$request = new PayPalCheckoutSdk\Orders\OrdersGetRequest($resource->id);
```

But this only returns RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND.

How can I get the Payerinfo here?

Answer (score 1):

The resource->id returned is a v2/payments id, not an Order ID.

v2/checkout/orders IDs are only used during payer approval, and have no accounting value.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! So I did a $request = new PayPalCheckoutSdk\Payments\CapturesGetRequest($resource->id); which works, but I'm still not getting any Payerinfo. What am I missing?

Comment: Perhaps the checkout.order.completed event https://developer.paypal.com/api/rest/webhooks/event-names/#orders would be more appropriate, if you truly need to get this information form a webhook. But I would never recommend doing so, orders integrations do not need to rely on webhooks for anything, the immediate synchronous response of an order capture will have nearly all the details (potentially with an additional 'get' call if necessary) https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Comment: Thanks a lot! I thought since the synchronous respond might result in a pending state, it's more reliant to use the webhooks. I'll do some tests with the synchronous response.